# BinningProcess: error in binning_transform_params parameter with metric = bins

Tags: python, scikit-learn, preprocessor, optbinning

I would like to use BinningProcess to transform columns in a sklearn pipeline. However, I would like BinningProcess to return bins instead of the mean of the target variable to have meaningful bins names.

To show my problem, I produce an example out of the sklearn pipeline. My understanding of the BinningProcess documentation is that I can handle the binning output format

**1. Either within the `.transform` method with the option `metric`.**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'continuous_feature': choices(range(0,30), k=95) + [np.NaN]*5,
                        'cat_feature': choices(['A', 'B', 'C'], k = 100),
                         'target' : [uniform(15,16) for x in range(0,100)]})

all_features = ["continuous_feature", "cat_feature"]
X = df.loc[:, all_features]
y = df.loc[:, 'target']

BinningProcess(all_features).fit_transform(X,y, metric = "bins")
```

this works fine and I obtain the desired table:

[image]

However, since I eventually want to use BinningProcess in a pipeline, I cannot use this .transform method option.

**2. Or within the BinningProcess function with the option `binning_transform_params`**

The equivalent code should be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'continuous_feature': choices(range(0,30), k=95) + [np.NaN]*5,
                    'cat_feature': choices(['A', 'B', 'C'], k = 100),
                     'target' : [uniform(15,16) for x in range(0,100)]})
all_features = ["continuous_feature", "cat_feature"]

X = df.loc[:, all_features]
y = df.loc[:, 'target']

BinningProcess(all_features,
               binning_transform_params = {"continuous_feature": {"metric": "bins"},
                                           "cat_feature": {"metric": "bins"}}).fit_transform(X,y)
```

Unfortunately, this yields an error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(-inf, 4.50)'
```

What could I to to prevent this error?

Also, binning_transform_params work well if I use another option than "bins", e.g. "indices" `{"continuous_feature": {"metric": "indices"}, "cat_feature": {"metric": "indices"}}`:

[image]

Comment: Issue on their github: https://github.com/guillermo-navas-palencia/optbinning/issues/266